# Array/2D Array or list

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a programm to do that do christmas orders.
So i add a new customer, then a new shopping item, then new order and finally i print the order details. The programm stops only when i type "quit".
So i have done all that, but i dont quit the programm and i continue adding new customers and orders, they must store somewhere. And Im wonderring if i must do an array, a 2D array or a list. Im not really sure that i know the difference. I tried to understand them and read a lot of articles in the net, but i still cant decide. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: You need a loop.  Learn control expressions for java

Comment: Im really sorry if this question is dumb and obvious but really dont understand

Comment: yeah for the different commands i have a while and a switch, but i must store the values somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could create an array of strings and each time a user enters a name, you create a new string in that array. For instance:

```
 String orders[]; 
 int numberOfOrder = 1;
 String name; 
 String item;
 String status;

 public class SomeClass(){

 orders = new String[certainSize];
 while(!status.equals("quit"){

     System.out.println("Name?");
     name = input.nextString(); 
     System.out.println("Item?");
     item = input.nextString();
     orders[orderNumber] = ("Name: "+name+" - Item: "+item+" - Order: "+numberOfOrder);
     numberOfOrder++; 
     System.out.println("Continue shopping?");
     status = input.nextString();

 }
```

Of course, you would have to create the scanner to read the input from the keyboard (I called the scanner input here). This is rudimentary and something I came up with from the top of my head but it should help you get started I hope!

PSA: I do not know if you can put "numberOfOrder" into the array size since it is changing all the time but you can try it.